# Not able to implement jQuery script CDN. Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined. Although I added the jQuery CDN at the top of my code

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I'm trying to render a datatable with jQuery CDN in my React.js project, but I got an error Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined.

I looked at some other solutions, most of them are the sequence of the script rendered.

and here is my code snippet:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'datatables.net'

const ViewCustomers = ( {fetchCustomers, userData, customerDetail, initialUpdate, updateSuccess} ) => {

    useEffect(() => {
        
        const script1 = document.createElement('script')
        // script1.defer = true
        script1.defer = true;
        script1.src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.js";

        document.head.appendChild(script1);

        
        const script2 = document.createElement('script')
        // script2.defer = true
        script2.src = "https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js";

        const script3 = document.createElement('script')
        // script3.defer = true
        script3.src = "https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.2/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js";

        const css1 = document.createElement('link')
        css1.rel = 'stylesheet'
        css1.href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css";

        const css2 = document.createElement('link')
        css2.rel = 'stylesheet'
        css2.href = "https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.2/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css";

        
        document.head.appendChild(script2);
        document.head.appendChild(script3);
        document.head.appendChild(css1);
        document.head.appendChild(css2);

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#example').DataTable();
        });

        fetchCustomers()
        initialUpdate()
        console.log(updateSuccess)

        return () => {
            document.head.removeChild(script1);
            document.head.removeChild(script2);
            document.head.removeChild(script3);
            document.head.removeChild(css1);
            document.head.removeChild(css2);
        }
    }, [])

    return userData ? (
        <div>
            <button 
                type="button" 
                className="btn btn-primary" 
                name="create"
                onClick={e => onClick(e)}>
                    <i class="bi bi-plus-square-fill"></i>Create
            </button>
            <form onSubmit={e => onSubmit(e)}>
                <table id="example" className="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">Serial</th>
                            <th scope="col">Customer Name</th>
                            <th scope="col">MAC</th>
                            <th scope="col">Action</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {
                            userData.map((customer, index) => {
                                return (
                                    <tr>
                                        <th scope="row">{index + 1}</th>
                                        <td>{customer.customer_name}</td>
                                        <td>{customer.customer_mac}</td>
                                        <td><button 
                                        type="submit" 
                                        name="cid"
                                        value={customer.id}
                                        className="btn btn-primary"
                                        onClick={ e => onClick(e) }
                                        >Modify</button></td>
                                    </tr>
                                )
                            })
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
    ) : (
        <div>
            Please login first {console.log(userData)}
        </div>
    )
};
```

I can also view the script rendered in the head of the code, and the jQuery script is rendered on the top.
[image: The script is rendered at the top of the code]

And I can view the jQuery package in the sources
[image: jQuery in the sources]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off using npm to install jquery as a dependency to your project.

`npm i jquery`

From: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery

And of course, the datatables extension.

`npm install datatables.net`

Best off checking the docs here: https://datatables.net/download/npm.

You can then use jQuery in your project by importing it:

`import $ from "jquery";`

Comment: Thanks for your reply Frish, but I did have installed the jQuery and datatables.net.

Comment: If you have installed them via npm then you don't need to load the scripts -- although I don't think this would be what's causing your issue necessarily.

Comment: I guess jQuery is just not that compatiable with React.js.